# How can I convert a list of dictionary(in json) into objects in python?

Tags: python, json, dictionary

> For example:
>   I have something like this 
>   `a=[{'id':1,'rating':123,'handle':'roshan'},{'id':2,'rating':423,'handle':'tippi'}]`(it can be more than two)
>   Is there any way to organize this kind of data in python?

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: Python Pandas works great for manipulating/filtering this kind of data...  but I'm not really sure what you are looking for.

Comment: I just want to know that Is there any way to make a single class(since each dictionary of the list have the same key) and read this data by using that class only?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want to convert this into an object with properties of the same name, I'd recommend using `namedtuple`, as it provides the least friction and you can just dump the contents of your dict into it using the double-star operator.

Example:

```
from collections import namedtuple

for data in [
    {'id': 1, 'rating': 123, 'handle': 'roshan'},
    {'id': 2, 'rating': 423, 'handle': 'tippi'}
]:
    Object = namedtuple("Object", ["id", "rating", "handle"])
    obj = Object(**data)
    print(obj.id, obj.rating, obj.handle)
```

See the documentation for more details on namedtuples https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple